# Two editions of Teshuvos Chasam Sofer

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, responsa

I am aware of two editions of the Responsa for Chasam Sofer: [Machon Meor](https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3727680-%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%96-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8) and [Machon Chasam Sofer](https://www.hbooks.co.il/product/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8---%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8). I was wondering what were the differences between the two, and if anyone could recommend one over the other, and why.

Here's what I think I know:

**Machon Meor**

- Came out first (?)
- Has footnotes
- Has index

**Machon Chasam Sofer**

- Also has index
- Has exclusive teshuvos in volume 7 (Machon Meor also has a volume 7 but the two are different...?)

Anything I'm missing? Is one more accurate (I assume Machon Chasam Sofer would be...)?

Comment: I'll add that I'm also curious about Machon Chatam sofer in general. Many of his works are published posthumously. I'm familiar with some of them but haven't learned in depth. Are things like his chiddushim on the torah, drashot, etc. based on what he actually wrote? Do they get redacted, censored, edited, etc? In other words, how confident can I be that these works are really true to what the chatam sofer wrote?

Comment: The footnotes in HaMaor's are excellent. They demonstrate a good grasp of where others, especially his son the Ketav Sofer, elaborate on his ideas further.